# Bootstrap navbar align right but need responsive to align left

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, menu, responsive-design, navbar

I used pull-right to align the top navbar to the right but when I resize the window and see the responsive menu, the list items are also aligned right, looks bunched up. How can I align the regular navbar menu right but the responsive menu items left?

There is no bootstrap-responsive.css in my download. Only bootstrap.css and bootstrap.min.css.

Thanks

Comment: can you post your code? BTW, you really need that bootstrap-responsive.css

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can remove float when design goes responsive simply use below css at the end of css

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
.navbar.pull-right {
float:none
}
}
```